# Azure connection idle timeout

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-configuration

Could you please show me how to manipulate Azure connection idle timeout?

Now I am using Azure VM and host my web application in IIS. My App calls rest service from the outside network and it takes 5-10 minutes to get the response back. I have read that Azure will close any connection if there is no response more than 4 minutes. I tried to set idle timeout to 30 minutes from the Azure portal public IP configuration, but it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: what exactly do you expect as response? Maybe it would be better to decouple your app using queue message. Let's say, after the response is ready, you save a text file and put a message on a queue. Than your web app just need to check the queue in order to check if the response is ready or not. I know I didn't answer your question, but this is how I would solve.

Comment: The response is an object that contains XML data. Anyway, thank you for the suggestion.